# How to simulate a low level keypress on os x?

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, macos, hid

I am trying to generate keyboard keydown and keyup events programmatically.  I am currently using CGPostKeyboardEvent to do this, but I am searching for a way to do this at a lower level.  I have looked at DDHidLib but could not figure out a way to create a fake event.  Can anyone help?

**update**: 
Thanks to weichsel's advice I am now creating a key down event with the following:

```
  CGEventRef e = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)52, true);
  CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, e);
  CFRelease(e);
```

which I found [here](http://www.openframeworks.cc/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2267).

**However**, my problem still stands so I will elaborate a bit.  The application (3rd party) that I would like to send keypresses to implements [DDHidLib's](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2007/03/19/ddhidlib_10/) key capturing function:

```
- (void) ddhidKeyboard: (DDHidKeyboard *) keyboard
             keyDown: (unsigned) usageId;
```

And this never gets called using the current method.  My guess is that the key down simulated with CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent is at too high of a level to be captured by ddhidKeyboard:keyDown.  So what I am trying to do is create the keydown event at a sufficiently low level such that it will be recognized by ddhidKeyboard:keyDown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's wrong with Quartz Event Services?
I think you are on the right track, but you should use [`CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent) instead of `CGPostKeyboardEvent` because the latter is deprecated since Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: Thanks!  I have updated the post per your suggestion, but it unfortunately did not fix my issue. I have provided some more info about the problem.

Comment: Hmmm. 
Does ddhidKeyboard recognize global keypresses if the app that implements it is not the front process?

Answer (score 3):

Event taps can inject at the HID level if you run as root

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGEventTapLocation

Comment: Good to know.  If I went this route, would that mean anytime a customer ran my app they would have to authenticate?

Comment: No. You can have a privileged helper tool that launchd runs for you.